# Paperclip + RSpec: content_type validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, paperclip

I am using `Paperclip` in my Rails application for attaching `images`.
I declared validation for `content_type` in my model as

```
 validates_attachment :image,
  :content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }
```

I have two examples, one with a valid image and other with an invalid image
For an invalid image, i just renamed a `.txt` file to a `.png`

```
 it "Image is valid" do
    image = File.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/support/right.png")
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:pin, image: image)).to be_valid
 end
 it "Image is invalid" do
   image = File.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/support/wrong.png")
   expect(FactoryGirl.build(:pin, image: image)).to have(1).errors_on(:image_content_type)
 end
```

I expected that both my examples should run successfully. BUT, my second example fails.
I don't get any error for content_type of `wrong.png`.

I thought that Paperclip's `content_type` validation would actually check file format(binary data encoding) of an uploaded file. BUT it seems that here, its just checking for the file extension. Does this validation only check extension of an uploaded file?

I maybe missing something here(configuration?). Is there any other validation available in Paperclip to achieve this? Or should I opt for a Custom Validator in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is resolved in Paperclip's latest version `4.1.1` released on `February 21, 2014`.

### Both of my following examples pass correctly now.

```
it "Image is valid" do
    image = File.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/support/right.png")
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:pin, image: image)).to be_valid
end
it "Image is invalid" do
   image = File.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/support/wrong.png")
   expect(FactoryGirl.build(:pin, image: image)).to have(1).errors_on(:image_content_type)
end
```

After a little bit of research found out that,
When I upload an `invalid image`,

For example: spoof(renamed) `wrong.txt` file as `wrong.png` and upload.

In prior release of Paperclip, `wrong.png` passes the `content_type` validation with flying colors without giving any error because `Paperclip` only used to `check the extensions` of the uploaded file and not content within.

Whereas, In the current release of `Paperclip 4.1.1`, same spoofed `wrong.png` fails the validation and throws the following error in view:

```
Image has an extension that does not match its contents
```

Upon investigating server log entries, I found the following:

> Command :: file -b --mime-type
>   '/var/folders/tg/8sxl1vss4fb0sqtcrv3lzcfm0000gn/T/a7f21d0002b0d9d91eb158d702cd930320140317-531-swkmb8'
>   [paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename wrong.png (["image/png"]),
>   content type discovered from file command: text/plain. See
>   documentation to allow this combination.

Here, you can see that Paperclip actually checked the content of the uploaded file stating `text/plain` and also erred out saying `Content Type Spoof`.

Hope my findings will help others to understand how `Paperclip's content-type` validation has improved over the time.