# Validate a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, image-uploading

I have a file field for people that want to upload a profile image:

```
<%= f.file_field :file %>
```

And it all works okay, however, I don't know how to validate it.

Here's my create action, and it's all working perfectly, but splitting the params hash like I'm doing is probably wrong:

```
def create
    new_user_params = user_params

    image_params = user_params[:profile_image_attributes]
    new_user_params.delete("profile_image_attributes")

    @user = User.new(new_user_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save

        @user.create_thumbnail(image_params)

        sign_in @user

        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Welcome to ' + request.host_with_port + ', ' + @user.user_name + '!' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

and here's the `user#create_thumbnail` method:

```
def create_thumbnail(data)

    upload =  data['file'].read

    img = Magick::Image.from_blob(upload).first

    img.resize!(75,75)      

    transaction do

        self.create_profile_image(path: 'test') 

        img.write 'test' + '.' + img.format.downcase

    end
end
```

Question:

Like it say, it all works perfectly, **but I'd like to know how to do it properly**, and, most importantly, **how to stop people uploading huge files and files that don't have the format .gif, .png .jpg or .jpeg** with appropriate validation error messages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open for adding a new gem then I would highly recommend using popular `Paperclip` gem which has built-in validations for `file size`, `content type/ extension` and `presence`.

Refer to **[Paperclip Github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)** Documentation.

It would be as simple as saying

```
validates_attachment :image, :presence => true,
  :content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] },
  :size => { :in => 0..10.kilobytes }
```

For a model with field named `image`(Paperclip attachment).

**Where:**

`:presence`  Validates that a file was attached while form submission

`:content_type` Validates file extensions(mime-type) specified. It will also check the actual content of the uploaded file. Read my **[findings here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610920/paperclip-rspec-content-type-validation).**

`:size` Validates the uploaded file size against the given range.

Comment: @user3067865 Did my answer help in resolving your issue? Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading files, you might want to use [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave).  They both come stocked with features to easily implement the problems you are encountering.

Paperclip:

You can use validates in the model:

```
validates_attachment_presence
validates_attachment_content_type
validates_attachment_size
```

Older RailsCast featuring paperclip: http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip

Carrierwave:

Has you specify an uploader class and from there you can add validations for file type and size.

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

Older RailsCast featuring Carrierwave: http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use a gem for that as carrierwave? https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

If you want to use your code why not to refactor a bit, for example

I would do something like this, using some design patterns.

```
def create_thumbnail
  upload_file(read_file(data))
  resize_img
  execute_transaction
end

def read_file(data)
 data['file'].read
end

def upload_file(read_file)
  Magick::Image.from_blob(read_file).first
end

def resize_img
 upload_file.resize!(75,75)
end

def execute_transaction
   transaction do

      self.create_profile_image(path: 'test') 

      img.write 'test' + '.' + img.format.downcase

   end
end
```